# ¿Como Manejar y validar Hora en un Formulario c#?

Tags: c#, formularios

¿Como  Manejar Hora en un Formulario c#?
¿cual seria el código para guardarla y validarla?

Adjunto Imagen de Ejemplo gráfico  de lo que quiero hacer 
Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
....

Saludos

Comment: Agrega más información y se especifico en tu pregunta. Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos

Comment: Gracias Jorge ya la edite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar el componente `DateTimePicker`, y colocar la propiedad 
`format = Time`, luego para validar las fechas puedes hacer algo así

```
    if (DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker1.Text) > DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Las 1 hora es mayor", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
    }
    else if (DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker1.Text) == DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Las horas son iguales", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
    }
    else if (DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker1.Text) < DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900 " + dateTimePicker2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Las 2 hora es mayor", "..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
    }
```

donde dateTimePicker1 y dateTimePicker2 son los componentes que uses en el form.

Comment: Me funciono Perfecto Gracias solo una duda ¿como deshabilito el botón que muestra el calendario?

Comment: coloca la propiedad ShowUpDown = true